# Office 365 - Remove domain from inaccessible tenant

Tags: office365, exchange-server, powerbi, office365api

I am trying to setup a new Office 365 tenant using a domain used on a previous tenant and I get the following warning – 
[image]

Is there a way to remove all users and the domain from Office 365 without access to the tenant that added it? I thought of admin takeover (opening a trial to PowerBI, taking admin ownership) and then releasing the domain so that it can be registered to the new Office 365 tenant but that requires a valid email address containing the domain and I don’t have that.

Know of a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove a domain from a Tenant without access to the Tenant that the domain was added to, and for very good reason.

If this was possible you would be able to destroy another company by removing their domain.
If you no longer have access to the Tenant the only way is to raise a ticket with Microsoft and ask them to help you get access to the Tenant. They will usually request details like addresses used for billing and information about the credit card used for the Tenant.

I have had to do this for a few customers over the years, it is always a long hellish process, but if there is no way you actually have the username and password anymore for the Tenant that has your domain verified it is the only way.